# Unable to start the cf-mysql-broker in pcf-dev

Tags: paas, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I am trying to set up the `pcf-dev` on an AWS instance (`m4.xlarge`). I'm able to start 46 processes out of 48. The remaining processes are unable to start.

Remaining processes: `cf-mysql-broker` ,`quota-enforcer`

```
root@agent-id-pcfdev-0:/var/vcap/sys/log/cf-mysql-broker# monit summary
The Monit daemon 5.2.5 uptime: 4h 8m

Process 'consul_agent'              running
Process 'mariadb_ctrl'              running
Process 'galera-healthcheck'        running
Process 'gra-log-purger-executable' running
Process 'cloud_controller_clock'    running
Process 'cloud_controller_ng'       running
Process 'cloud_controller_worker_local_1' running
Process 'cloud_controller_worker_local_2' running
Process 'nginx_cc'                  running
Process 'cloud_controller_migration' running
Process 'cloud_controller_worker_1' running
Process 'blobstore_nginx'           running
Process 'blobstore_url_signer'      running
Process 'doppler'                   running
Process 'gorouter'                  running
Process 'loggregator_trafficcontroller' running
Process 'metron_agent'              running
Process 'nats'                      running
Process 'route_registrar'           running
Process 'uaa'                       running
Process 'etcd'                      running
Process 'garden'                    running
Process 'auctioneer'                running
Process 'bbs'                       running
Process 'cc_uploader'               running
Process 'converger'                 running
Process 'file_server'               running
Process 'nsync_listener'            running
Process 'nsync_bulker'              running
Process 'rep'                       running
Process 'route_emitter'             running
Process 'ssh_proxy'                 running
Process 'stager'                    running
Process 'tps_listener'              running
Process 'tps_watcher'               running
Process 'syslog-configurator'       running
Process 'process-watcher'           running
Process 'cf-redis-broker'           running
Process 'broker-nginx'              running
Process 'cf-redis-route-registrar'  running
Process 'cf-mysql-broker'           not monitored
Process 'cf-mysql-route-registrar'  running
Process 'quota-enforcer'            not monitored
Process 'rabbitmq-broker'           running
Process 'rabbitmq-broker-route-registrar' running
Process 'rabbitmq-management-route-registrar' running
Process 'rabbitmq-server'           running
System 'system_localhost'           running
root@agent-id-pcfdev-0:/var/vcap/sys/log/cf-mysql-broker#
```

I verified the logs in the `/var/vcap/sys/log/cf-mysql-broker` path and did not find any error.

Answer (score 1):

Pivotal does not officially support running PCF Dev on AWS. We publish an AWS Vagrant box for use with our own CI systems only. AWS functionality for users is on the roadmap, but it probably won't be ready for several months. We may even temporarily stop publishing AWS boxes at some point in the future.

That said, our CI pipeline deploys PCF Dev to m4.xlarge instances every day, many times a day. How are you starting PCF Dev? Are you deploying with a different `PCFDEV_DOMAIN`? Have you modified the Vagrantfile? Can you post the output from `vagrant up`?

We find that using a 400 GB EBS root volume improves I/O performance significantly. Can you try running `AWS_EBS_DISK_SIZE=400 vagrant up --provider=aws`?

-Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.. Stephen..

I am running the Vagrant using "vagrant up --provider=aws" by providing the aws credentials and domain. Vagrant will start the 48 CF process, so in my case it stared 46 process and unable to start the 2 process and it keep polls the message saying that "Starting process 46 of 48". When I check in the CF instance "cf-mysql-broker ,quota-enforcer" process are failed to start.